# MaxImage: No animation effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've made a simple one-pager with the MaxImage plugin (Background image slider). I've copied a previously made WordPress template and used it as base for this new splashpage.

The MaxImage plugin has no animation effect on the new site, while this works perfectly on the original site.

Original: http://kirstenfotografeert.nl/

New: http://www.misterymusic.com/

What am I missing or not seeing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the new one image switching is working. What is your problem

Comment: The switching is working fine on both sites. The problem is the fade-animation on the new site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Looks like it works when the mouse is NOT hovering the image. Any chance you have enabled pause on mouse-over?</s>

**EDIT:
You are missing jquery.maximage.min.css on your new website. This CSS file adds the opacity transition on the elements.**

Comment: The switching is working fine on both sites. The problem is the fade-animation on the new site. Even when my pointer is on the footer (.bottom-bar), the fade animation is not there.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Updated my answer.